# Please help me with Django model object validation

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm very new to Django and programming in general. I'm trying to do some Django admin model object validations. I'm implementing bid system. User must be able to bid and edit bids straight from admin page. The code may be far from perfect...
Here's models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class category(models.Model):
    category =  models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Enter new category')
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.category}"


class bid(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey('listing', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, null=True, decimal_places=2)
    
    def clean(self):
        if self.bid <= self.listing.Price:
            raise ValidationError('Please place a bid higher than starting price')

        if self.bid <= ??? #How should I code this?
            raise ValidationError('Please place a bid higher than the current highest bid')
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}, {self.listing} {self.bid}"


class listing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    Price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="categories")
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Title}"
```

Answer (score 0):

clean is for a form not a model, this can be done by implementing a custom ModelAdmin for class bid with its custom validation and do the validation in that form